# Make a method to go through the list of all objects and make a new list with specific objects

Tags: python, list, class, methods

I need to make a method called `filter` in the main class `Vehicles`, with 2 arguments that go through the list `all_vehicles`, and add to the `new_list`, all the objects of that class that was passed by argument. And at the end make a print of the `new list, new_list`.

For example:

```py
def filter(vehicles, name_of_vehicle):
    new_list = []
    print(f"From list {vehicles} found {name_of_vehicle}")

vehicles_listed = filter(all_vehicles, "Car")
```

And the print should look something like this.

```py
"From the list all_vehicles were found [car1, car2, car3]".
```

```py
class Vehicles:
    color = ''
    wheels = []
    
    def __init__(self, color, wheels):
        self.color = color
        self.wheels = wheels
        
    def filter(vehicles, name_of_vehicle):
    new_list = []
    print(f"From list {vehicles} found {name_of_vehicle}")
    
    def __str__(self):
        print(f"The bus is {self.color} and has {self.wheels} wheels.")
bus1 = Vehicles("white", 6)
bus1.__str__()
bus2 = Vehicles("blue", 6)
bus2.__str__()

class Car(Vehicles):
    speed = 0
    displacement = 0
    
    def __init__(self, color, wheels, speed, displacement):
        super().__init__(color, wheels)
        self.color = color
        self.wheels = wheels
        self.speed = speed
        self.displacement = displacement
    
    def __str__(self):
        print(f"The car is {self.color}, has {self.wheels} wheels, is traveling at {self.speed} mph and has {self.displacement} displacement.")

car1 = Car("black", 4, 70, 1000)
car1.__str__()
car2 = Car("grey", 4, 65, 950)
car2.__str__()
car3 = Car("green", 4, 90, 1100)
car3.__str__()

class Truck(Car):
    cargo = 0
    
    def __init__(self, color, wheels, speed, displacement, cargo):
        super().__init__(color, wheels, speed, displacement)
        self.color = color
        self.wheels = wheels
        self.speed = speed
        self.displacement = displacement
        self.cargo = cargo
        
    def __str__(self):
        print(f"The truck is {self.color}, has {self.wheels} wheels, is traveling at {self.speed} mph, has {self.displacement} displacement and is carrying {self.cargo} weight as cargo.")
        
truck1 = Truck("grey", 4, 40, 900, 1.525)
truck1.__str__()
truck2 = Truck("white", 4, 45, 920, 2.253)
truck2.__str__()

class Bike(Vehicles):
    gears = ""
    
    def __init__(self, color, wheels, gears):
        super().__init__(color, wheels)
        self.color = color
        self.wheels = wheels
        self.gears = gears
        
    def __str__(self):
        print(f"The bike is {self.color}, has {self.wheels} wheels and has {self.gears} changes.")
        
bike1 = Bike("orange", 2, 12)
bike1.__str__()
bike2 = Bike("black", 2, 10)
bike2.__str__()

class Motorbike(Bike):
    speed = 0
    displacement = 0
    model = ""
    
    def __init__(self, color, wheels, gears, speed, displacement, model):
        super().__init__(color, wheels, gears)
        self.color = color
        self.wheels = wheels
        self.gears = gears
        self.speed = speed
        self.displacement = displacement
        self.model = model

    def __str__(self):
        print(f"The motorbike is {self.color}, has {self.wheels} wheels, has {self.gears} changes, is traveling at {self.speed} mph, has {self.displacement} displacement and is a {self.model} motorbike.")

motorbike1 = Motorbike("blue", 2, 5, 120, 600, "road")
motorbike1.__str__()
motorbike2 = Motorbike("black", 2, 7, 220, 1100, "race")
motorbike2.__str__()

all_vehicles = [bus1, bus2, car1, car2, car3, truck1, truck2, bike1, bike2, motorbike1, motorbike2]

def catalog(the_list, wheels):
  num = 0
  for vehicle in the_list:
    if vehicle.wheels == wheels:
      num += 1

  print(f"Found {num} vehicles with {wheels} wheels.")

catalog(all_vehicles, 6)
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

First off, **you should not name your method** `filter`, since there is already a built-it function called `filter` in Python which you can see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter). This could cause confusion for people that look at your code, and also cause what is called shadowing (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) for more detail)

I suggest you name your method `filter_vehicles` instead.

Now, onto the code, we can use `type().__name__` to get the string of an object. Here's a quick example via the Python interactive shell:

```py
>>> class Car:
...     def __init__(self, name):
...             self.name = name
...
>>> class Motorcycle(Car):
...     def __init__(self, name):
...             super().__init__(name)
...
>>> a = Motorcycle("motor1")
>>> type(a).__name__
'Motorcycle'
```

Now back to your code, we can compare the type name to the provided vehicle name like so:

```py
def filter_vehicles(vehicle_list, name):
    new_vehicle_list = []
    for v in vehicle_list:
        #compare the typename to the name passed to the method
        if type(v).__name__ == name:
            new_vehicle_list.append(v.name)
    return new_vehicle_list
```

Another, more concise way to do this is with list comprehension. You can learn more about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp):

```py
def filter_vehicles(vehicle_list, name):
    return [v.name for v in vehicle_list if type(v).__name__ == name]
```

Note that in order to properly print out the vehicle name. It is best to add a `self.name` attribute to the `Vehicle` class and its children and display that out, since you cannot display nor keep the variable names when it is changed to a list.

Another thing is that for my definition I returned the list instead of printing it out. If you really want to do that feel free, but do note that printing the result inside a method without returning anything is quite unconventional.